# Can git-svn not rewrite git history?

Tags: git, git-svn

I commit changes to git-svn repository, the SHA of my commit is AAAA. After I dcommit, the SHA becomes BBBB.

I understand the SHA changes because git-svn stores SVN metadata.

Is it possible for git-svn not to change SHA but still able to svn rebase and dcommit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for git not to change the SHA, a new SHA is created for any new commit including a rebase.

Comment: How about dcommit, can Git not change SHA?

Comment: You could git svn clone with the —no-metadata flag but that is not recommended because you lose the svn versión numbers. Otherwise the meta data will change the commit hash and a new SHA will be generated.

Comment: the —no-metadata flag disallows me from dcommit.. is there a workaround?

Comment: Unfortunatly there is not a workaround. The svn metadata will always create a new SHA and commit and it appears dcommit will not work without the meta data.